# Intent is not working between classes in one file

Tags: android

my problem is - Intent is not working between classes in one file. The aplication is building with no error, it can be installed, but, when im on `act_2_1_getting_started` and try to go to `pod1` pushing the button `option1`, the screen becomes white for a 2 second and it gets me to activity before `act_2_1_getting_started` (activity that is in another file and has button thats taking me to act_2_1_getting_started by intent). I think that problem solution is very easy, i`m nameing something wrong, but i dont know what. I need to have more than one classes in one file. Can anyone help. Here is a code:

```
public class act_2_1_getting_started extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_2_1_getting_started);

        TextView story = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.story);
        story.setText("Text1");
        Button option1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.option1:
                intent = new Intent(this, pod1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }


    }

}
```

And another class in the same file:

```
class pod1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState1) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState1);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_2_1_getting_started);

        TextView story = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.story) ;
        story.setText("Text2");
        Button option1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.option1:
                intent = new Intent(this, anoth.class );
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, you should read [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) on Java naming conventions

Comment: Make your pod1 class a public class. 
If pod1 is in defferent package, then act_2_1_getting_started class will not be able to access it.

Comment: But when im making pod1 class a public class, Android Studio gives me two possibilities - make it ont public, oraz move it to pod1.class, co that it will be in another file.

Comment: Sol How would You solve it, just more than one classes in one file and making possible to use intent between them ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the AndroidManifest.xml file. Has you defined the pod1 activity there?

The logcat is surely showing you the error when trying to start the new activity.

By the way, try to respect the Java naming conventions, do not use "_" and start the class name with a capital letter.

Regards

**EDIT**

If what you want is to have 2 activities within one java file (I don't know why, is not a good approach), this is the way:

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState1) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState1);
    }

    public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState1) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState1);
        }
    }

}
```

Then, you can add the inner Activity in the manifest this way:

```
<activity android:name="<package_name>.Activity1$Activity2"/>
```

This kind of classes are called "nested classes", but they are intended for other purposes, so rather use different java files.

Comment: In AndroidManifest.xml it gives me no permission to define it, because it is not public. As I presented You a code, it build with no errors, install, but work not properly. Can You tell how to put more than one class on one file, and make possible intent between them ?

Comment: You have to make it public, the Activity Class must be accessed from outside the package. It is required that you add it to the manifest or the activity won't be launched (the error log will tell you this).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help to prevent white screen.. put this 
`<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>` in your style..Now your style will look like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="cardViewStyle">@style/CardView</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:textDirection">locale</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: white screen is not a problem, im decribing it as a cause of main problem, that not woirking intent betwen classes in one file.